# Does a placeholder in a trailing-return-type override an initial placeholder?

Tags: c++, decltype, c++14, trailing-return-type, return-type-deduction

g++ appears to accept any combination of `auto` and `decltype(auto)` as initial and trailing return types:

```
int a;
auto f() { return (a); }                             // int
auto g() -> auto { return (a); }                     // int
auto h() -> decltype(auto) { return (a); }           // int&
decltype(auto) i() { return (a); }                   // int&
decltype(auto) j() -> auto { return (a); }           // int
decltype(auto) k() -> decltype(auto) { return (a); } // int&
```

However, clang rejects `j` and `k`, saying: *error: function with trailing return type must specify return type 'auto', not 'decltype(auto)'* ([demonstration](http://goo.gl/uw5h0b)).

Which compiler is correct? Which rule (`auto` or `decltype(auto)`) should be used in each case? And does it make any sense to use a placeholder type in a *trailing-return-type*?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`auto` is required when introducing a *trailing-return-type*.

§8.3.5 [dcl.fct] /2

> In a declaration `T D` where `D` has the form
>
> > `D1 (` *`parameter-declaration-clause`* ) *`cv-qualifier-seq`<sub>opt</sub>
> >      `ref-qualifier`<sub>opt</sub> `exception-specification`<sub>opt</sub> `attribute-specifier-seq`<sub>opt</sub> `trailing-return-type`*
> >
> > and the type of the contained *declarator-id* in the declaration `T D1` is “derived-*declarator-type-list* `T`”,
>
> **`T` shall be the single *type-specifier* auto.** [...]

See also [Core Issue 1852](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_toc.html#1852) for the apparent contradiction with [dcl.spec.auto]/1.

Comment: You should report this as a bug with GCC, btw.

Answer (score 3):

Edit after [@Xeo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/500104/xeo) constructive comments:

It seems that this issue is due a contradiction between two places of the draft standard.

According to the draft standard *§ 7.1.6.4 auto specifier [dcl.spec.auto]:*

> `1` The `auto` and `decltype(auto)` **type-specifiers designate a placeholder type** that will be replaced later, either by deduction from an initializer or by explicit specification with a trailing-return-type. The auto type-specifier
>   is also used to signify that a lambda is a generic lambda.
>
> `2` The placeholder type can appear with a function declarator in the decl-specifier-seq, type-specifier-seq,
>   conversion-function-id, or **trailing-return-type**, in any context where such a declarator is valid. If the function
>   declarator includes a trailing-return-type (8.3.5), that specifies the declared return type of the function.
>   **If the declared return type of the function contains a placeholder type, the return type of the function is
>   deduced from return statements in the body of the function, if any.**

The sole interpretation of the above would suggest that Clang has a bug.

However, as [core issue 1852](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1852) specifies the above contradict with *§ 8.3.5/2 Functions [dcl.fct]* and should be altered. The status of the issue is ready which suggests that the the changes have been accepted.

As such, the GCC has a bug that should be reported.

Comment: The syntax for the trailing return type is `auto ... -> T`, where `T` can be a placeholder type. The `auto` at the beginning is mandatory.

Comment: @Xeo Read the first sentence of the quote. It says `decltype(auto)` can also be replaced by `trailing-return-type` which is the `-> T` syntax.

Comment: Please see [Core Issue 1852](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1852).

Comment: @Xeo so you are suggesting that there's a contradiction in the standard?

Comment: First, there is no Standard containing those words, yet. It's a draft. And yes, there is a contradiction, as can be seen by the CWG issue and the fact that it's "Ready", meaning the resolution was accepted.

Comment: @Xeo First of all thank you for your intervention, really productive. This suggest that the things are the other way around and that GCC has the bug.