# auto, decltype(auto) and trailing return type

Tags: c++, c++14, auto, decltype, trailing-return-type

Is there a difference between:

```
template <class T>
constexpr decltype(auto) f(T&& x) -> decltype(std::get<0>(std::forward<T>(x)))
{
    return std::get<0>(std::forward<T>(x));
}
```

and:

```
template <class T>
constexpr auto f(T&& x) -> decltype(std::get<0>(std::forward<T>(x)))
{
    return std::get<0>(std::forward<T>(x));
}
```

and if so, what is it, and which one should I use for perfect forwarding?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369113/what-is-the-difference-between-auto-and-decltypeauto-when-returning-from-a-fun. Why do you need the `-> ...` part if you are writing for C++14?

Comment: @kennytm SFINAE based on the arguments

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Trailing return type should only be used with `auto`

The point of `decltype(auto)` vs `auto` is to [distinguish the case whether the return type should be a reference or value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369113/what-is-the-difference-between-auto-and-decltypeauto-when-returning-from-a-fun). But in your case the return type is already explicitly defined as `decltype(std::get<0>(std::forward<T>(x)))`, so it will be perfectly-forwarded even if you use `auto`.

In `auto f() -> T`, the "auto" keyword is simply a [syntactic construct to fill in a type position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224325/what-is-the-meaning-of-auto-when-using-c-trailing-return-type). It serves no other purpose.

---

In fact, in C++17 you *cannot* use a `decltype(auto)` with trailing-return-type together.

C++14 wordings (n3936 §7.1.6.4[dcl.spec.auto]/1):

> The `auto` and `decltype(auto)` *type-specifiers* designate a placeholder type that will be replaced later, either by deduction from an initializer or by explicit specification with a *trailing-return-type*. The `auto` *type-specifier* is also used to signify that a lambda is a generic lambda.

C++17 wordings (n4618 §7.1.7.4[dcl.spec.auto]/1):

> The `auto` and `decltype(auto)` *type-specifiers* are used to designate a placeholder type that will be replaced later by deduction from an initializer. The `auto` *type-specifier* is also used to introduce a function type having a *trailing-return-type* or to signify that a lambda is a generic lambda (5.1.5). The `auto` *type-specifier* is also used to introduce a decomposition declaration (8.5).

This is [DR 1852](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1852), see [Does a placeholder in a trailing-return-type override an initial placeholder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24259947/does-a-placeholder-in-a-trailing-return-type-override-an-initial-placeholder).

Practically, while `gcc` accepts `decltype(auto) f() -> T` ([which is a bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67012)), but `clang` will **reject** it saying

```
error: function with trailing return type must specify return type 'auto',
not 'decltype(auto)'
```